# Removing the first rows before a specific value - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove all rows before an initial value for a group. For instance, if my `max_value = 250`, then all rows for a group before that value should be removed. If a consequtive value of 250 or less appears again for that group, it is not removed.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-01', '2019-04-01',
             '2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-01', '2019-04-01',
             '2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-01', '2019-04-01'],
    'Asset': ['Asset A', 'Asset A', 'Asset A', 'Asset A', 'Asset A', 'Asset A', 'Asset B', 'Asset B',
             'Asset B', 'Asset B', 'Asset B', 'Asset B'],
    'Monthly Value': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 100, 200, 300, 200, 300, 200]
})

unique_list = list(df['Asset'].unique())
max_value = 250
print(df)

          date    Asset  Monthly Value
0   2019-01-01  Asset A            100
1   2019-02-01  Asset A            200
2   2019-03-01  Asset A            300
3   2019-04-01  Asset A            400
4   2019-01-01  Asset A            500
5   2019-02-01  Asset A            600
6   2019-03-01  Asset B            100
7   2019-04-01  Asset B            200
8   2019-01-01  Asset B            300
9   2019-02-01  Asset B            200
10  2019-03-01  Asset B            300
11  2019-04-01  Asset B            200
```

if the threshold or `max_value` is 250, then the dataframe should look like this (below). Notice the first time a value under 250 is detected for a group, all of those rows are removed. If the value 250 or higher is shown again, it is kept. Any help would be appreciated.

```
          date    Asset  Monthly Value
2   2019-03-01  Asset A            300
3   2019-04-01  Asset A            400
4   2019-01-01  Asset A            500
5   2019-02-01  Asset A            600
8   2019-01-01  Asset B            300
9   2019-02-01  Asset B            200
10  2019-03-01  Asset B            300
11  2019-04-01  Asset B            200
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df[df.groupby('Asset')['Monthly Value'].apply(lambda x: x.gt(max_value).cumsum().ne(0))]
```

Yields:

```
          date    Asset  Monthly Value
2   2019-03-01  Asset A            300
3   2019-04-01  Asset A            400
4   2019-01-01  Asset A            500
5   2019-02-01  Asset A            600
8   2019-01-01  Asset B            300
9   2019-02-01  Asset B            200
10  2019-03-01  Asset B            300
11  2019-04-01  Asset B            200
```

Additionally, if you store your max values in a dictionary like `max_value = {'Asset A': 250, 'Asset B': 250}`, you can do the following to achieve the same result:

```
df[df.groupby('Asset')['Monthly Value'].apply(lambda x: x.gt(max_value[x.name]).cumsum().ne(0))]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it works perfect on my proxy data. One thing I missed is that there will be a max_value for each group (asset) (list or pandas column). if `max_value_list = [250, 300], I cannot replace it for `max_value` in your formula. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cool solution. simply change the 'gt' to 'isin'

Comment: @sammywemmy: `isin` doesn't work. it checks on equality while OP checks on `gt`

Comment: Updated my answer to account for your additional condition

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `apply`. Groupby on boolean series to create the mask to slice the desired output. As your new requirement that each group slice on different `max_value`. You need to create a dictionary using unique values of `Asset` and `max_value_list` and map it to `Asset` column to create a series `s` of max_values. Finally, compare `Monthly Value` against `s` and groupby `cumsum` to create mask `m` for slicing. (**Note**: *I change your sample to different values to show slicing on different `max_values`*)

```
Modified sample `df` to show slicing on different max_value

Out[334]:
          date    Asset  Monthly Value
0   2019-01-01  Asset A            100
1   2019-02-01  Asset A            200
2   2019-03-01  Asset A            300
3   2019-04-01  Asset A            400
4   2019-01-01  Asset A            500
5   2019-02-01  Asset A            600
6   2019-03-01  Asset B            100
7   2019-04-01  Asset B            350
8   2019-01-01  Asset B            450
9   2019-02-01  Asset B            200
10  2019-03-01  Asset B            300
11  2019-04-01  Asset B            200

max_value_list = [250, 300]
max_dict = dict(zip(df.Asset.unique(), max_value_list))
s = df.Asset.map(max_dict)
m = (df['Monthly Value'] > s).groupby(df.Asset).cumsum().ne(0)
df[m]

Out[333]:
          date    Asset  Monthly Value
2   2019-03-01  Asset A            300
3   2019-04-01  Asset A            400
4   2019-01-01  Asset A            500
5   2019-02-01  Asset A            600
7   2019-04-01  Asset B            350
8   2019-01-01  Asset B            450
9   2019-02-01  Asset B            200
10  2019-03-01  Asset B            300
11  2019-04-01  Asset B            200
```